Split and match names in a df with another df and return the matching firms
Please help me with this particular scenario. I've been able to partially do this but the final dataframe does not look correct for all the rows.
I have two Dataframes:
df1:



Name




A/B/C


D/E


F/G



df2:



First Name
Last Name
Firm Names




Adam
A
Firm1


Harry
B
Firm1


Andrew
C
Firm1


Mike
A
Firm2


Sheila
D
Firm3


Hash
E
Firm3


Michelle
F
Firm4


Morty
G
Firm4



Now df1 contains only the last names with a slash(/). I want to match the last names in df1 with df2 and when it finds a common firm name for all of A and B and C for example then return that firm name for that row. If you notice A/B/C in df1 there are multiple firm names for the same last name in df2. I only want the common firm name for all the three last names in that row.
So my final data frame should look something like this :



Name
Firm Name




A/B/C
Firm1


D/E
Firm2


F/G
Firm3




You can use a simple merge with a key as frozenset, no need to explode:
out = df1.merge(df2.groupby(['Firm Names'], as_index=False)
                ['Last Name'].agg(frozenset),
                left_on=df1['Name'].str.split('/').apply(frozenset),
                right_on='Last Name'
               ).drop(columns='Last Name')

Output:
    Name Firm Names
0  A/B/C      Firm1
1    D/E      Firm3
2    F/G      Firm4

Handling other columns
If you have other columns and they are matching the Firm Names (i.e., a given First Name has a single Address), then just include those in the groupby, if the values are different for a given Firm Name, you have to aggregate. Below is an example of both:
out = df1.merge(df2.groupby(['Firm Names', 'Address'], as_index=False)
                   .agg({'Last Name': frozenset, 'ID': ','.join}),
                left_on=df1['Name'].str.split('/').apply(frozenset),
                right_on='Last Name'
               ).drop(columns='Last Name')

Example:
    Name Firm Names Address     ID
0  A/B/C      Firm1     ABC  a,b,c
1    D/E      Firm3     GHI    e,f
2    F/G      Firm4     JKL    g,h

Modified df2:
  First Name Last Name Firm Names Address ID
0       Adam         A      Firm1     ABC  a
1      Harry         B      Firm1     ABC  b
2     Andrew         C      Firm1     ABC  c
3       Mike         A      Firm2     DEF  d
4     Sheila         D      Firm3     GHI  e
5       Hash         E      Firm3     GHI  f
6   Michelle         F      Firm4     JKL  g
7      Morty         G      Firm4     JKL  h

pre-filtering df2:
valid_names = '/'.join(df1['Name']).split('/')

out = df1.merge(df2[df2['Last Name'].isin(valid_names)]
                   .groupby(['Firm Names', 'Address'], as_index=False)
                   .agg({'Last Name': frozenset}),
                left_on=df1['Name'].str.split('/').apply(frozenset),
                right_on='Last Name', how='left'
               ).drop(columns='Last Name')

Output:
    Name Firm Names Address
0  A/B/C      Firm1      MA
1    D/E      Firm3      PS

Used input:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A/B/C', 'D/E']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'First Name': ['Adam', 'Harry', 'Andrew', 'Mike', 'Sheila', 'Hash', 'ABC'],
                    'Last Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'XYZ'], 
                    'Firm Names': ['Firm1', 'Firm1', 'Firm1', 'Firm2', 'Firm3', 'Firm3','Firm1'], 
                    'Address':['MA', 'MA', 'MA', 'BO', 'PS', 'PS', 'MA']})


is there a way i can add more columns to this above expression. For example if my data set contains address along with the Firm Name..can i get both the columns?

@olivia yes you can how to do it depends if the values are the same for a given "Firm Name" or not, can you provide a small example? I provided an example for both cases

provided a sample df
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A/B/C', 'D/E']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'First Name': ['Adam', 'Harry', 'Andrew', 'Mike', 'Sheila', 'Hash', 'ABC'], 'Last Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'XYZ'], 'Firm Names': ['Firm1', 'Firm1', 'Firm1', 'Firm2', 'Firm3', 'Firm3','Firm1'], 'Address':['MA', 'MA', 'MA', 'BO', 'PS', 'PS', 'MA']})
i want the matching firm names and address mapped to A/B/C and D/E

And what should be the expected output (and why?) Should GARRISON/SCHUSTER/SHULL not match because of ABC?

just edited the df @mozway  i want the matching firm names and address mapped to A/B/C and D/E

@olivia but there is no exact match with A/B/C since df2 has A/B/C/XYZ, should you ignore XYZ?

yes ignore XYZ since that's not a part of out first dataframe df1..df1 only contains A/B/C and D/E(just and example)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@olivia I added an update with pre-filtering and handling of Address

this works perfectly. thank you so much. I've learnt so much from this. One more thing i encountered while testing:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A/B/C', 'D/E','H/H']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'First Name': ['Adam', 'Harry', 'Andrew', 'Mike', 'Sheila', 'Hash', 'ABC','Tom','Peter','Don'], 'Last Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'XYZ','H','H','H'], 'Firm Names': ['Firm1', 'Firm1', 'Firm1', 'Firm2', 'Firm3', 'Firm3','Firm1','Firm5','Firm6','Firm5'], 'Address':['MA', 'MA', 'MA', 'BO', 'PS', 'PS', 'MA','','','']})
when i have the same last name eg H/H i get both the firm names in the df

@olivia that's expected since you have two matches, a merge will produce one row per combination. If you want you can only keep the first match by adding .drop_duplicates('Last Name') after .agg({'Last Name': frozenset})

If ordering of Last Names is same in both DataFrames is possible use:
out = df1[['Name']].merge((df1['Name'].str.split('/')
                                     .explode()
                                     .rename('Last Name')
                                     .reset_index()
                                     .merge(df2, how='left')
                                     .groupby(['index','Firm Names'])
                                     .agg(Name=('Last Name', '/'.join))
                                     .reset_index(level=1)), how='left')
print (out)
    Name Firm Names
0  A/B/C      Firm1
1    D/E      Firm3
2    F/G      Firm4

More general solution is use frozensets for matching fimes with any ordering:
First create frozensets with splitted values to helper DataFrame - df1:
df11 = df1.assign(**{'Last Name':df1['Name'].str.split('/'),
                    'sets':lambda x: x['Last Name'].apply(frozenset)})
print (df11)
    Name  Last Name       sets
0  A/B/C  [A, B, C]  (B, A, C)
1    D/E     [D, E]     (D, E)
2    F/G     [F, G]     (F, G)

Use DataFrame.explode for column from lists and left join with second DataFrame by DataFrame.merge, create sets for each firm names:
df22 =  (df11.explode('Last Name')
             .reset_index()
             .merge(df2, how='left')
             .groupby(['index','Firm Names'])
             .agg(sets=('Last Name', frozenset))
             .reset_index(level=1))
print (df22)
      Firm Names       sets
index                      
0          Firm1  (B, A, C)
0          Firm2        (A)
1          Firm3     (D, E)
2          Firm4     (F, G)

Last left join to original df1 and filter columns names:
out = df11.merge(df22, how='left')[['Name','Firm Names']]
print (out)
    Name Firm Names
0  A/B/C      Firm1
1    D/E      Firm3
2    F/G      Firm4


Wow, that is really nice answer. I've learned a lot from it!

@jezrael - thank you for the solution. i can't seem to get the firm names mapped when in df22. the firm names return as blanks.

@olivia - Do you test it with sample data?

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A/B/C', 'D/E', 'F/G']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'First Name': ['Adam', 'Harry', 'Andrew', 'Mike', 'Sheila', 'Hash', 'Michelle', 'Morty'], 'Last Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 'Firm Names': ['Firm1', 'Firm1', 'Firm1', 'Firm2', 'Firm3', 'Firm3', 'Firm4', 'Firm4']})

@jezrael - thank you, this worked perfectly for 99% of the cases. One such case that i saw while testing was : df1 = {'Name': ['A/B/C', 'D/E', 'F/G', H/H]} and df2 = {'First Name': ['Adam', 'Harry', 'Andrew', 'Mike', 'Sheila', 'Hash', 'Michelle', 'Morty', 'Tom', 'Peter', 'Don'], 'Last Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'H', 'H'], 'Firm Names': ['Firm1', 'Firm1', 'Firm1', 'Firm2', 'Firm3', 'Firm3', 'Firm4', 'Firm4', 'Firm5', 'Firm6', 'Firm5']}
last two names-i get all the records like H/H - Firm5, HH - Firm6 but i should only get Firm 5 since that's the only one that matches

import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["A/B/C","D/E","F/G"]}).rename(columns= {"Name":"Last Name"})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'First Name': ['Adam', 'Harry', 'Andrew', 'Mike', 'Sheila', 'Hash', 'Michelle', 'Morty'], 'Last Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 'Firm Names': ['Firm1', 'Firm1', 'Firm1', 'Firm2', 'Firm3', 'Firm3', 'Firm4', 'Firm4']})

unique_firms = df2["Firm Names"].unique()
splitted_names = [set(n.split("/")) for n in df1["Last Name"]]
firm_dict = {firm:set(df2[df2["Firm Names"] == firm]["Last Name"]) for firm in unique_firms}

data1 = [('/'.join(v),k) for k,v in firm_dict.items() if v in splitted_names]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data1 , columns=["Name", "Firm Name"])

output:



Name
Firm Name




A/B/C
Firm1


D/E
Firm2


F/G
Firm3



If you need to keep the first names and all the firms as well use the following code:
data2 = [(firm,'/'.join(list(df2[df2["Firm Names"] == firm]["Last Name"])),'/'.join(list(df2[df2["Firm Names"] == firm]["First Name"]))) for firm in unique_firms]
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=["Name", "    Last Name", "Firm Name"])

output:



Firm Names
Last Name
First Name




Firm1
A/B/C
Adam/Harry/Andrew


Firm2
A
Mike


Firm3
D/E
Sheila/Hash


Firm4
F/G
Michelle/Morty




In pandas is best not iterate values, check this

@jezrael thank you very much for your feedback, I'll read this article.
